# In R, how do you find out each time a value is represented in a column OF VECTORS and construct a dataframe based on results?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I'm stuck on an R issue and hope someone can help. I've never posted a question on Stack Overflow so I hope I'm doing this right.

I have a dataframe where one of the columns is a column of vectors. It looks like this:

```
area <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
population <- c(500, 300, 400, 300, 250)
sites <- c("c(A, B, C)", "c(A, B)", "c(A, C)", "c(A)", "c(B, C)")

data <- data.frame(area, population, sites)
data
```

I need it to look like this:

```
site <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Area <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "5", "1", "3", "5")
population <- c(500, 300, 400, 300, 500, 300, 250, 500, 400, 250)

df <- data.frame(site, Area, population)
df
```

To do this, I'll need to record the area and population each time a site appears in a vector and put that information into a new data frame. Each site appears in each vector one time at the most (i.e., it's not possible in my data to have a vector where one site appears twice).

Please comment if you have any tips.

Comment: How did that `sites` column get made? Things would be easier here if it could be created as a `list` column, but that would be an upstream fix. Do you have control over how it's created?

Comment: In your example `sites` isn't a column of vectors - it's a column of characters, because the quotes are outside of each `c()`. Is that correct? Or should it be `sites = c(c("A, B, C"), c("A, B"), c("A, C"), c("A"), c("B, C"))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data in column `sites` are really strings of the form `"c(A, B, C)"`, here is a `tidyverse` option using `separate_rows`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    mutate(sites = str_remove_all(sites, "c\\(|\\)")) %>%
    separate_rows(sites, sep = ", ")
## A tibble: 10 x 3
#   area  population sites
#   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>
# 1 1            500 A    
# 2 1            500 B    
# 3 1            500 C    
# 4 2            300 A    
# 5 2            300 B    
# 6 3            400 A    
# 7 3            400 C    
# 8 4            300 A    
# 9 5            250 B    
#10 5            250 C
```

To match the ordering of `df` you can `arrange(sites)`.

---

If column `sites` is in fact a `list` column, a simple `data %>% unnest(sites)` will expand data in that column.